# NullPointerException not passing in JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, nullpointerexception

I'm having trouble getting my `NullPointerException` test case to pass.

```
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyCustomStringTest {

    private MyCustomStringInterface mycustomstring;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mycustomstring = new MyCustomString();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        mycustomstring = null;
    }


    // Test if a null point exception is thrown  
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testCountNumbers2() {
        mycustomstring.setString(null);
        assertNull(mycustomstring.countNumbers());
    }
}
```

This test keeps failing even if I check that it's not null. Here's the implementation for `mycustomstring` and `countNumbers()`.

```
public class MyCustomString implements MyCustomStringInterface {
private String string;

@Override
public String getString() {
    return string;
}

@Override
public void setString(String string) {
    this.string = string;
}

@Override
public int countNumbers() {
    StringBuffer tmpString = new StringBuffer();
    int count=0;
    boolean inNumber=false;
    //avoid null pointer exception!
    if(string==null || string.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char ch = string.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            if (!inNumber) {
                count++;
                inNumber = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (inNumber) {
                inNumber = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

`int countNumbers();` returns a string that consists of all characters in the original string with each segment of `n` characters reversed. If `padded` is true, the final segment of characters will have the character 'X' added to it enough time to make:

```
* a full segment.
* <p>
* <p>
* Examples:
* - For n=2 and padded=true, the method would return the string with every pair of characters swapped in place, and
* if there were an odd number of characters, an X would be added to the last segment before it is reversed.
* - For n=3 and padded=false, the method would return the string with every segment of 3 characters reversed in place,
* and the final segment would be reversed even if less than 3 characters without any additional characters added.
* <p>
* Values n and padded are passed as parameters. The starting character is considered to be in Position 1.
*
* @param n       Determines size of the string segments to be reversed
* @param padded Determines whether an incomplete final segment will be padded with 'X'.
* @return String with the segments in their original order and the contents of the segments reversed.
* @throws NullPointerException        If the current string is null or uninitialized.
* @throws IllegalArgumentException    If "n" less than or equal to zero, and the current string is not null.
*/
```

Comment: Whats in `MyCustomString`? Does it even throw a NPE?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of countNumbers method inside of the MyCustomString.class?

Comment: Also, which version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: can you post the MyCustomString class implementation?

Comment: I added them . .

Comment: Why do you ever expect an NPE? Where would you get one?

Comment: `This test keeps failing even if I check if its not null.` This test keeps failing __because__ you check if its null.

Answer (score 0):

Your `countNumbers()` method returns an `int` which means a result is always returned. So when you run:

```
assertNull(mycustomstring.countNumbers());
```

the `int` value is autoboxed to an `Integer` and is never `null`. Further, `countNumbers()` never throws a `NullPointerException`, so the expectation that one will be thrown is never met.

Whichever of these JUnit checks first is causing your test to fail every time.